# How to extract text using regex in vb6

Tags: regex, vb6

How to extract text using regex in vb6

```
Dim MyText As String

MyText = "anything [*]textToExtract[*] anything"
```

**Result Should Be :**

textToExtract

Comment: How are you using regular expressions in VB 6? You have to be using some kind of custom library, in which case you'll need to make sure that your code follows the syntax used by that library.

Comment: @Cody : Microsoft VBScript Regular Expressions 5.5

Comment: @Cody The reference the OP accepted in his previous question pointed him to use VBScript.

Comment: @Cody Gray: anyone who needs RegEx in VB6 uses the Microsoft Regular Expression parser which is part of any Windows systems younger than 10 years.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
Sub test()
    Dim re As RegExp, m As MatchCollection
    Set re = New RegExp
    Dim MyText As String, extractedText As String
    MyText = "anything textToExtract anything"

    re.Pattern = "anything (.*) anything"
    Set m = re.Execute(MyText)
    extractedText = m(0).SubMatches(0)

End Sub
```